# "Invalid Arithmetic Operator" when doing floating-point math in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, math

Here is my script:

```
d1=0.003
d2=0.0008
d1d2=$((d1 + d2))

mean1=7
mean2=5
meandiff=$((mean1 - mean2))

echo $meandiff
echo $d1d2
```

But instead of getting my intended output of:

```
0.0038
2
```

I am getting the error `Invalid Arithmetic Operator, (error token is ".003")?`

Comment: BTW, if you switched from bash to ksh93, floating-point would be natively available.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`bash` does not support floating-point arithmetic. You need to use an external utility like `bc`.

```
# Like everything else in shell, these are strings, not
# floating-point values
d1=0.003
d2=0.0008

# bc parses its input to perform math
d1d2=$(echo "$d1 + $d2" | bc)

# These, too, are strings (not integers)
mean1=7
mean2=5

# $((...)) is a built-in construct that can parse
# its contents as integers; valid identifiers
# are recursively resolved as variables.
meandiff=$((mean1 - mean2))
```

Comment: It just *doesn't*. `bash` was not written with support for floating-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 14):

Another way to calculate floating numbers, is by using [AWK rounding](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html) capability, for example:

```
a=502.709672592
b=501.627497268
echo "$a $b" | awk '{print $1 - $2}'

1.08218
```

Comment: This answer is much better.

Comment: Excellent alternative.

Comment: for me bc command was not present in the yocto build. awk is a life saver. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

In case you do not need floating point precision, you may simply strip off the decimal part.

`echo $var | cut -d "." -f 1 | cut -d "," -f 1`

cuts the integer part of the value. The reason to use cut twice is to parse integer part in case a regional setting may use dots to separate decimals and some others may use commas.

**Edit**:

Or, to automate the regional settings one may use `locale`.

`echo $var | cut -d $(locale decimal_point) -f 1`

Comment: Actually, you should probably check for the correct separator. If you simply cut with both that might be really bad with some (i.e. US?) standards of havin comma for thousands and points for decimals. Your script would cut `1,005.3` to 1 instead of 1005.

Comment: @bufu Sure. Actually one can check that via locale. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I did not know there was a `locale` to do this. Have my upvote, good sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the shell which you are using. If you are executing your script with bash shell `bash scriptname.sh` try using ksh for your script execution. Bash doesn't support arithmetic operations that involve floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Big shout-out to the `bc` command - it totally saved my day! It's a simple answer, but it worked like a charm.

```
a=1.1
b=1.1

echo $a + $b | bc -l
# Output:
2.2

#SUM
sum=$(echo $a + $b | bc -l) 
echo $sum
# Output
2.2
```

`bc` is a command-line calculator, which allows users to perform mathematical calculations on the terminal.