# Bash For-loops with Floats

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a for loop which goes from 0.01 to 0.10

According to [1], bash does not support floating-point arithmetic, and one needs to use an external utility like bc.

I tried the following:

```
initial=0.01
end=0.1
inc=0.01
for ((test="$initial" | bc; test<"$end" | bc; test+="$inc" | bc))
do
    echo "done with: $test" | bc 
done
```

I get an error saying:

> ((: test=0.01 | bc: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error
>   token is ".01 | bc")

Any ideas about how this could be implemented?

[1] ["Invalid Arithmetic Operator" doing floating-point math in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634255/invalid-arithmetic-operator-doing-floating-point-math-in-bash)

Comment: `for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do printf -v num "0.%02d\n" $i; echo $num; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in $(LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 seq $initial $inc $end); do echo $i; done
```

Output:

```
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.10
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `bc` for comparison and computations, that may be needed with other loop conditions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set numeric format to POSIX to avoid
# floating point representation discrepancies
# between bc and printf '%f'
LC_NUMERIC=POSIX

initial=0.01
end=0.1
inc=0.01

cur=${initial}
while [[ $(bc <<<"${cur} < ${end}") -eq 1 ]]; do
  printf '%f\n' "${cur}"
  cur="$(bc <<<"${cur} + ${inc}")"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need floating-point arithmetics to loop from 0.01 to 0.10. Instead, you can use the fact, that in your case, you are basically iterating from `1` to `10`, zero-padding that number to 2 places and prefixing it with `0.`:

```
for i in {1..10}
do 
  printf "0.%02s\n" "$i"
done
```

Note that this approach requires you to match the field width given to `printf` to the number of decimal places you want to use, e.g. if you want to go from `0.001` to `0.1`, you would have to write `{1..100}` and `printf "0.%03s\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use `seq`.

The following script

```bash
#!/bin/usr/env bash

initial=0.01
end=0.1
inc=0.01

for i in $(seq $initial $inc $end)
do
   echo $i
done
```

gives the output:

```
0.01
0.02
0.03
0.04
0.05
0.06
0.07
0.08
0.09
0.1
```